# Error when trying to delete a post in my Next.js application using Prisma and Zod

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, httprequest, prisma

I'm currently working on a Next.js project where I'm trying to delete a post by its **`id`** using Prisma as my ORM and Zod for data validation. The client-side component sends a DELETE request to an API route on my server and should include the **`id`** of the post to be deleted in the request body.

Here's my client-side function to handle deletion:

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
  if (!post?.id) return;
  try {
    await axios.delete(`/api/subreddit/post/delete/`, {
      data: { postId: post.id },
    });
    toast({
      title: "Success",
      description: "Post was deleted successfully",
    });
    router.refresh(); // Refresh the page or redirect the user.
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // Log the error message
    return toast({
      title: 'Something went wrong.',
      description: "Post wasn't deleted successfully. Please try again.",
      variant: 'destructive',
    })
  }
};
```

My server-side function looks like this:

```
export async function DELETE(req: Request) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const { postId } = z.object({
      postId: z.string(),
    }).parse(body);

    const session = await getAuthSession();

    if (!session?.user) {
      return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    const post = await db.post.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: postId,
      },
    });

    if (!post) {
      return new Response("Post not found", { status: 404 });
    }

    if (post.authorId !== session.user.id) {
      return new Response("You do not have permission to delete this post", { status: 403 });
    }

    await db.post.delete({
      where: {
        id: postId,
      },
    });

    return new Response("Post Deleted");
  } catch (error:any) {
    console.log('Error when deleting post:', error.message);
    if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
      return new Response(error.message, { status: 400 });
    }

    return new Response(
      "Could not delete post at this time. Please try later",
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to delete a post:

```
[
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "postId"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  }
]
```

This error suggests that **`postId`** is **`undefined`**. I'm not sure why this is happening because I'm providing a **`postId`** in my DELETE request from the client side. Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried to console log the request and try to figure out the issue from there, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: `const body = await req.json();` after this line, can you `console.log(body)`

Comment: @Yilmaz iv'e tried but nothing shows up in the console

Comment: check the terminal. `route` files are server files not browser file

Comment: @Yilmaz I just get  'Error when deleting post:', 'Unexpected end of JSON input'

Answer (score 1):

updating next.js fixes the issues as this was a bug in next.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code but used a literal string "test" for the Axios body.

After doing this, the parsing didn't fail, and the code works as expected.

Verify that the post.id type is 100% a string, otherwise, I don't see a problem.

Here is the mock code I used:

`Server code:`

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { z } from "zod"

export async function DELETE(req: Request) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json()
    const { postId } = z
      .object({
        postId: z.string(),
      })
      .parse(body)

    return NextResponse.json("success", { status: 200 })
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log("Error when deleting post:", error.message)
    if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
      return new Response(error.message, { status: 400 })
    }

    return new Response(
      "Could not delete post at this time. Please try later",
      { status: 500 }
    )
  }
}
```

`client code:`

```
"use client"

import axios from "axios"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"

const page = () => {
  return <Button onClick={handleDelete}>delete</Button>
}
export default page

const handleDelete = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`/api/delete`, {
      data: { postId: "test" },
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I checked the types and it is a string that is passing but I still get 'Error when deleting post:',
'Unexpected end of JSON input' on my endpoint error.message

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and resolved it after reading the answers here.

I personally believe that the key to the problem lies in the format of the input parameters. And I really hope that your problem has been perfectly solved! (My English is suck and my code is suck.)

I used Prisma here↓

client code

```
export async function deleteFur(param) {
  try {
    console.log("param", param); // {id: 1}
    const raw = await axios.delete("/api/furniture", {
      data: JSON.stringify(param), // json
    });
    console.log(raw);
    const { data } = raw;
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

server code

```
import db from "@/lib/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function DELETE(req, res) {
  try {
    const payload = await req.json(); // get it
    const deletedAppliance = await db.appliance.delete({
      where: payload,
    });
    return NextResponse.json({
      status: 201,
      message: deletedAppliance,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.error({ status: 500, message: err });
  }
}
```